# Items not displaying orderwise in Recycler View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

In my Recycler View not displaying the item orderwise routinely changing the items for each and every time while running the program.
How to display  Order wise the items in Recycler View.

Code:

```
 final CustomLinearLayoutManagercartpage layoutManager = new CustomLinearLayoutManagercartpage(CartItems.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
 recyleitems.setHasFixedSize(false);
 recyleitems.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
 cartadapter = new CartlistAdapter(cart, CartItems.this);
 Log.i(String.valueOf(cartadapter), "cartadapter");
 recyleitems.setAdapter(cartadapter);
 recyleitems.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
 myView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 cartadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Adapter:

```
public class CartlistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < CartlistAdapter.ViewHolder > {

    private ArrayList < CartItemoriginal > cartlistadp;
    private ArrayList < Cartitemoringinaltwo > cartlistadp2;
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    private Context context;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    public static final String MYCARTPREFERENCE = "CartPrefs";
    public static final String MyCartQtyPreference = "Cartatyid";
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    SharedPreferences shared,
    wishshared;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editors;
    String pos,
    qtyDelete;
    String date;
    String currentDateandTime;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_ONE = 1;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_TWO = 2;
    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private Double orderTotal = 0.00;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0");
    Double extPrice;
    View layout,
    layouts;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor QutId;

    boolean flag = false;


    public CartlistAdapter() {

    }
    public CartlistAdapter(ArrayList < CartItemoriginal > cartlistadp, Context context) {

        this.cartlistadp = cartlistadp;
        this.cartlistadp2 = cartlistadp2;
        this.context = context;
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisk(true).cacheInMemory(true).showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.b2)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.b2).build();
        if (YelloPage.imageLoader.isInited()) {
            YelloPage.imageLoader.destroy();
        }
        YelloPage.imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
    }


    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if (cartlistadp.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(cartlistadp), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return VIEW_TYPE_TWO;
        }
        return VIEW_TYPE_ONE;


    }


    @Override
    public CartlistAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        switch (position) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_TWO:
                View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_cart, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view2, new MyTextWatcher(viewGroup, position));
                // return view holder for your placeholder
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_ONE:
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cartitemrow, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view, new MyTextWatcher(view, position));
                // return view holder for your normal list item
                break;
        }
        return viewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CartlistAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.productnames.setText(cartlistadp.get(position).getProductname());
        viewHolder.cartalisname.setText(cartlistadp.get(position).getAliasname());
        viewHolder.cartprice.setText("Rs" + " " + cartlistadp.get(position).getPrice());
        viewHolder.cartdelivery.setText(cartlistadp.get(position).getDelivery());
        viewHolder.cartshippin.setText(cartlistadp.get(position).getShippincharge());
        viewHolder.cartsellername.setText(cartlistadp.get(position).getSellername());
        viewHolder.Error.setText(cartlistadp.get(position).getError());
        viewHolder.qty.setTag(cartlistadp.get(position));
        viewHolder.myTextWatcher.updatePosition(position);
        if (cartlistadp.get(position).getQty() != 0) {
            viewHolder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(cartlistadp.get(position).getQty()));
            viewHolder.itemView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder.qty.setText("0");
        }
        YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(cartlistadp.get(position).getProductimg(), viewHolder.cartitemimg, options);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cartlistadp.size();
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return cartlistadp.get(position);
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView productnames, cartalisname, cartprice, cartdelivery, cartshippin, cartsellername, Error, total;
        private ImageView cartitemimg;
        private ImageButton wishbtn, removebtn;
        private LinearLayout removecart, movewishlist;
        private CardView cd;
        private EditText qty;
        private ImageView WishImg;
        public MyTextWatcher myTextWatcher;

        public ViewHolder(final View view, MyTextWatcher myTextWatcher) {
            super(view);
            productnames = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cartitemname);
            cartalisname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cartalias);
            cartprice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CartAmt);
            cartdelivery = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cartdel);
            cartshippin = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shippingcrg);
            cartsellername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cartSellerName);
            cartitemimg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cartimg);
            Error = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.error);
            this.myTextWatcher = myTextWatcher;

            removecart = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.removecart);
            movewishlist = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.movewishlist);

            WishImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wishimg);



            qty = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            qty.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);

            String pid, qid;

            sharedPreferences = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(MYCARTPREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            QutId = sharedPreferences.edit();
            Log.d("Position checking1 ---", String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()));
            //MyTextWatcher textWatcher = new MyTextWatcher(view,qty);
            //  qty.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(view,getAdapterPosition()));
            //qty.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);


            qty.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    qty.setSelection(qty.getText().length());
                    return false;
                }
            });

            wishshared = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editors = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();


            shared = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(MYCARTPREFERENCE, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(MYCARTPREFERENCE, context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();


            cd = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            productnames.setSingleLine(false);
            productnames.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
            productnames.setMaxLines(2);

            //totalPrice();

            view.setClickable(true);
            //  view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

            removecart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (cartlistadp.size() == 1) {
                        Intent list = new Intent(v.getContext(), Cart.class);
                        context.startActivity(list);
                        ((Activity) context).finish();
                        removeAt(getAdapterPosition());
                        Log.i(String.valueOf(getPosition()), "item");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "All items deleted from your WishList", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        removeAt(getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                }
            });
            MovewishList();
            totalPrice();
        }


        private void totalPrice() {
            int price = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < cartlistadp.size(); j++) {
                price += Integer.parseInt(cartlistadp.get(j).getPrice()) * (cartlistadp.get(j).getQty());
                String totalprice = String.valueOf(price);
                String count = String.valueOf(cartlistadp.size());
                CartItems.Totalamt.setText(totalprice);
                CartItems.cartcount.setText("(" + count + ")");
                CartItems.carttotalcount.setText("(" + count + ")");
            }
        }


        public void removeAt(int positions) {
            JSONArray test = new JSONArray();
            JSONArray test1 = new JSONArray();
            JSONArray test2 = new JSONArray();

            JSONArray item = null;
            JSONArray itemsQty = null;
            test1.put("0");
            test2.put("0");
            test.put(test1);
            test.put(test2);
            String channel = shared.getString(Constants.cartid, String.valueOf(test));
            pos = cartlistadp.get(getAdapterPosition()).getProductid();
            qtyDelete = String.valueOf(cartlistadp.get(getAdapterPosition()).getQty());

            try {
                JSONArray delteitems = new JSONArray(channel);

                itemsQty = delteitems.getJSONArray(0);
                item = delteitems.getJSONArray(1);

                for (int x = 0; x < itemsQty.length(); x++) {

                    if (pos.equalsIgnoreCase(itemsQty.getString(x))) {
                        itemsQty.remove(x);
                        cartlistadp.remove(positions);
                        notifyItemRemoved(positions);
                        notifyItemRangeChanged(positions, cartlistadp.size());
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                for (int y = 0; y < item.length(); y++) {
                    if (qtyDelete.equalsIgnoreCase(item.getString(y)))
                        item.remove(y);
                }
                String s = String.valueOf(delteitems);
                editor.putString(Constants.cartid, String.valueOf(delteitems));
                editor.apply();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


        public void MovewishList() {



            movewishlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (cartlistadp.size() == 1) {
                        pos = cartlistadp.get(getAdapterPosition()).getProductid();
                        JSONArray items3;
                        if (!flag) {
                            //    wishlist.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wishnew);
                            flag = true;
                            String channel = wishshared.getString(Constants.productid, "['']");
                            JSONArray items;
                            String wishitem;
                            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(channel)) {
                                items = new JSONArray();
                                items.put(String.valueOf(pos));
                                wishitem = String.valueOf(items);
                                editors.putString(Constants.productid, wishitem);
                                editors.apply();
                                removeAt(getAdapterPosition());
                                Toast.makeText(context, "cartItems", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                flag = false;

                            } else {

                                try {

                                    Boolean found = false;
                                    items = new JSONArray(channel);
                                    for (int x = 0; x < items.length(); x++) {
                                        if (pos.equalsIgnoreCase(items.getString(x))) {
                                            found = true;
                                            removeAt(getAdapterPosition());
                                            Toast.makeText(context, "cartItems1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (!found) {
                                        items.put(String.valueOf(pos));
                                        wishitem = String.valueOf(items);
                                        editors.putString(Constants.productid, wishitem);
                                        removeAt(getAdapterPosition());
                                        Toast.makeText(context, Constants.productid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        Log.i(Constants.productid, "wishitems");

                                    }
                                    editors.apply();
                                    flag = false;

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }

                            Intent list = new Intent(view.getContext(), Cart.class);
                            context.startActivity(list);
                            ((Activity) context).finish();
                        } else {
                            removeAt(getAdapterPosition());
                            Intent list = new Intent(view.getContext(), Cart.class);
                            context.startActivity(list);
                            ((Activity) context).finish();
                        }


                    } else {

                        pos = cartlistadp.get(getAdapterPosition()).getProductid();
                        if (!flag) {
                            //    wishlist.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wishnew);
                            flag = true;

                            String channel = wishshared.getString(Constants.productid, "['']");
                            JSONArray items;
                            String wishitem;
                            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(channel)) {
                                items = new JSONArray();
                                items.put(String.valueOf(pos));
                                wishitem = String.valueOf(items);
                                editors.putString(Constants.productid, wishitem);
                                editors.apply();
                                removeAt(getAdapterPosition());
                                Toast.makeText(context, "cartItems", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                flag = false;

                            } else {

                                try {

                                    Boolean found = false;
                                    items = new JSONArray(channel);
                                    for (int x = 0; x < items.length(); x++) {
                                        if (pos.equalsIgnoreCase(items.getString(x))) {
                                            found = true;
                                            removeAt(getAdapterPosition());
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (!found) {
                                        items.put(String.valueOf(pos));
                                        wishitem = String.valueOf(items);
                                        editors.putString(Constants.productid, wishitem);
                                        removeAt(getAdapterPosition());
                                        Log.i(Constants.productid, "wishitems");
                                    }
                                    editors.apply();
                                    flag = false;

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            removeAt(getAdapterPosition());
                        }

                    }

                }



            });

        }




    }

    public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

        private int min, max;

        public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
            this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
            this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            try {
                int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
                if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                    return null;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {}
            return "";
        }

        private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
            return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
        }
    }


    private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        private View view;
        private EditText editText;
        private int position;

        //private int position;
        private MyTextWatcher(View view, int position) {
            this.view = view;
            this.position = position;
            // this.position = adapterPosition;


            //  cartlistadp.get(position).getQty() = Integer.parseInt((Caption.getText().toString()));
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //do nothing
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //   EditText qtyView = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);

            Log.i("editextpostion", String.valueOf(position));
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0");
            String qtyString = s.toString();
            int quantity = qtyString.equals("") ? 0 : Integer.valueOf(qtyString);
            String quty = String.valueOf(quantity);

            EditText qtyView = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            CartItemoriginal product = (CartItemoriginal) qtyView.getTag();

            //   int position = (int) view.qtyView.getTag();

            Log.d("postion is qtytag", "Position is: " + product);
            qtyView.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
                new InputFilterMinMax(product.getMinquantity(), product.getMaxquantity())
            });

            if (product.getQty() != quantity) {

                Double currPrice = product.getExt();
                Double price = Double.parseDouble(product.getPrice());
                int maxaty = Integer.parseInt(product.getMaxquantity());
                int minqty = Integer.parseInt(product.getMinquantity());

                if (quantity < maxaty) {
                    extPrice = quantity * price;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry" + " " + " " + "we are shipping only" + " " + " " + maxaty + "  " + " " + "unit of quantity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                Double priceDiff = Double.valueOf(df.format(extPrice - currPrice));

                product.setQty(quantity);
                product.setExt(extPrice);

                TextView ext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CartAmt);

                if (product.getQty() != 0) {
                    ext.setText("Rs." + " " + df.format(product.getExt()));
                } else {
                    ext.setText("0");
                }


                if (product.getQty() != 0) {
                    qtyView.setText(String.valueOf(product.getQty()));
                } else {
                    qtyView.setText("");
                }


                JSONArray test = new JSONArray();
                JSONArray test1 = new JSONArray();
                JSONArray test2 = new JSONArray();
                JSONArray items = null;
                JSONArray itemsQty = null;
                test1.put("0");
                test2.put("0");
                test.put(test1);
                test.put(test2);
                JSONArray listitems = null;
                //String Sharedqty= String.valueOf(cartlistadp.get(getAdapterPosition()).getQty());


                String channel = (shared.getString(Constants.cartid, String.valueOf(test)));

                try {
                    listitems = new JSONArray(channel);
                    itemsQty = listitems.getJSONArray(1);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    if (itemsQty != null) {
                        itemsQty.put(position + 1, qtyString);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    if (listitems != null) {
                        listitems.put(1, itemsQty);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                QutId.putString(Constants.cartid, String.valueOf(listitems));
                QutId.apply();

                Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(listitems), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                totalPrice();
            }

            return;
        }

        private void totalPrice() {
            int price = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < cartlistadp.size(); j++) {
                price += Integer.parseInt(cartlistadp.get(j).getPrice()) * (cartlistadp.get(j).getQty());
                String totalprice = String.valueOf(price);
                String count = String.valueOf(cartlistadp.size());
                CartItems.Totalamt.setText(totalprice);
                CartItems.cartcount.setText("(" + count + ")");
                CartItems.carttotalcount.setText("(" + count + ")");
            }
        }

        public void updatePosition(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }
    }




}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: isn't enough for this code

Comment: show your code of adapter

Comment: updated above my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sorting you need to Collection.sort method of Java and also you need to implement comparable interface for define your comparison.

```
CartItemoriginal implements Comparable {
     public int compareTo(Object obj)  { }  }
```

Updated

```
public class CartItemoriginal implements Comparable<CartItemoriginal > {

    private Float val;
    private String id;

    public CartItemoriginal (Float val, String id){
        this.val = val;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ToSort f) {

        if (val.floatValue() > f.val.floatValue()) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (val.floatValue() <  f.val.floatValue()) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

and use

```
Collections.sort(sortList);
```

Comment: I have doubt why recycler View  not displaying the orderwise  items

Comment: Have you tried Collections.sort(list) when all data is added to list and compare method you have to compare object on any field by which you want to sort? Recycler view displaying list as given.

Comment: i didn't used collection,i didn't compare it on any field,Can u provide me example

Comment: I have to create seperate class cartiemoriginal because that is my model class

Comment: No just you need to implement Comparable interface in your model class.

Comment: Before displaying list in recylcler view